Find Time Periods in pandas where value changes and meets threshold
I have time series data time, which has time and an integer measurement co2 and I want to find the first time when co2 > 1000 and from that point when co2 < 500.
I've tried a number of things but am stuck trying to find these periods in time.
I can certainly get all start_times and end_times of periods, but there has to be a better way to calculate the durations of these periods when CO2 > 1000, and then < 500.
d = {'time': ['2024-06-13 18:18:00','2024-06-13 18:18:01','2024-06-13 18:18:02','2024-06-13 18:18:03','2024-06-13 18:18:04','2024-06-13 18:18:05','2024-06-13 18:18:06'], 'co2': [0,1000,1000,500,1000,1000,500]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])

start_times = df[df.co2>=1000]['time']
end_times = df[df.co2<=500]['time']
start_times, end_times

I believe I should be able to find all these periods like the following:



index
start
end




1
2024-06-13 18:18:01
2024-06-13 18:18:03


2
2024-06-13 18:18:04
2024-06-13 18:18:06




I've tried grouping them, maybe I need to detect when the bin class changes with Shift?

I think you're on the right track with establishing categories and conducting a groupby.  In my solution here (using Pandas 2.2.1) I first create an "event" column in the dataframe to indicate those timestamps for which "co2" is > 500 and <= 1,000.  Then, you can use np.cumsum() to add an identifier to groups of timestamps that have the same "event" designation (i.e., True or False).  Finally, filter down to "True" events, group by the event id, and gather the minimum and maximum timestamps.  Note that based on your example I added a second to the maximum timestamp to align with your expected results (this approach will work if your time intervals are constant over your entire data set).  Also, for this to work you have to convert the "time" column into an actual datetime object.  Here you go:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'time': ['2024-06-13 18:18:00','2024-06-13 18:18:01','2024-06-13
18:18:02','2024-06-13 18:18:03','2024-06-13 18:18:04','2024-06-13
18:18:05','2024-06-13 18:18:06'], 'co2': [0,1000,1000,500,1000,1000,500]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

high = 1000
low = 500
df["event"] = (df["co2"] > low) & (df["co2"] <= high)
df["event_id"] = np.cumsum(df["event"] != df["event"].shift(1))
df.loc[df["event"]].groupby("event_id").agg(
    start_time=pd.NamedAgg(column="time", aggfunc="min"),
    end_time=pd.NamedAgg(column="time", aggfunc=lambda x: x.max() + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s'))
)

This results in:


First create a mask to filter the rows where co2 is bigger than 500 and lower than 1000.
After that create the groups based on co2 lower or equal than 500. We groupby to create the start and end columns. Use query to filter every row where start and end are equal.
m = df['co2'].ge(1000) | df['co2'].le(500)
g = df.loc[::-1, 'co2'].le(500).cumsum()
result = (df[m].groupby(g, sort=False)['time']
          .agg(start='first', end='last')
          .query('start != end')
          .reset_index(drop=True)
         )

End result:
              start                 end
2024-06-13 18:18:01 2024-06-13 18:18:03
2024-06-13 18:18:04 2024-06-13 18:18:06


I'll answer my own question.
I found a method for what I was looking for, which might not be the most elegant, but does appear to find the periods.
The first step is to Bin based on the right values.
Then we can detect a change with those bins.
then I can loop thru those changes by two's to grab start and end building the periods.
def findTimePeriods(df,low=500,high=1000):
    # Used for Testing
    start_times = df[df.co2>=high]['time']
    end_times = df[df.co2<=low]['time']
    print(len(start_times),len(end_times))
    
    # Setup the Bins for this dataset.
    bins = [0,1000,2000,3000]
    labels = ['0-1000','1001-2000','2001-3000']
    df['co2_bins'] = pd.cut(df['co2'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
    print(len(df['co2_bins']))
    df["isStatusChanged"] = df["co2_bins"].shift(1, fill_value=df["co2_bins"].iloc[0]) != df["co2_bins"]
    periods = []
    # Iterate thru the status changes
    t = df[df['isStatusChanged']].iterrows()
    for (i, row1), (j, row2) in zip (t,t):
        periods.append(
            {
                "start_time":row1['time'],
                "end_time":row2['time'],
                "duration": (row2['time']-row1['time'])
            }
        )
        

    return periods

[{'start_time': '2024-06-13 18:18:01', 'end_time': '2024-06-13 18:18:03'},
 {'start_time': '2024-06-13 18:18:04', 'end_time': '2024-06-13 18:18:06'}]

